# Makefile .PHONY target does not work as expected

Tags: makefile

I am writing a simple Makefile for practicing .PHONY target

```
#!/bin/make
dir/%/compile:
     @echo "The target '$@ had been built'"
```

In my working directory, the directory layout is as below

```
├── dir
│   └── subdir
│       └── compile
└── Makefile
```

When I type **make dir/subdir/compile**, it claimed the target is up to date as below

```
make: `dir/subdir/compile' is up to date.
```

It's right. 
But it still claimed the target is up to date even a **.PHONY** target is added as below

```
#/bin/make
.PHONY: dir/%/compile
dir/%/compile:
     @echo "The target '$@ had been built'"
```

As I know .PHONY can build the target unconditionally no matter the target exists or not
However, it seemed not works as it should be. Could anyone help me figure it out? Thanks

Comment: You have made a mistake on your [shabang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) I think you wanted to write: `#!/bin/make`

Comment: @jml Yes, that was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use patterns with `.PHONY`.  Only true target names will work.  You're just saying that the literal target named `dir/%/compile` is phony.

Comment: Yes. After I changed the pattern to a true target name, it works
However, I am wondering if there is any chance to make the pattern target rule being built every time?

Comment: @shwang You might be interested in reading [__this__](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html) then.

Comment: @Chnossos Oh, that is exactly what I want. thanks a lot for your informatin